# With WinUI3 and C#, how do you take a Observable list of Image paths and display them as a horizontal list that fills width?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I have a list of image paths and would like to display the images they refer to in a single horizontal row. The width of each image should be the same and they should all fill the Window's height or their allocated width as the window is resized.

I tried to do this with a StackPanel, but it does not resize the images like a Grid with *-sizing would.

```
    <ItemsControl
        x:Name="HandImages"
        Padding="5"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image  
                    Source="{Binding}"
                    Tapped="ImageTapped"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill"
                    FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource ImagePreviewFlyout}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [UniformGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid) from the **Windows CommunityToolkit** and use it as an `ItemsPanel`.

1. Name your page. We need to to do this to do bindings from the `DataTemplate` to the `Items.Count` property in the page.
2. Install the **CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Primitives** NuGet package.
3. And this:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:UniformGrid
                Columns="{Binding ElementName=RootPage, Path=Items.Count}"
                Rows="0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I did not want to add more dependencies, so I ended up using C# to build the grid based on the callbacks from an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this programmatically with minimal XAML. Here is the XAML I used.

```xml
    <Grid x:Name="HandGrid"
          RowDefinitions="*">
        
    </Grid>
```

Then create an observable collection of the views. I used this in my case.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<string> images = new();
```

Then, add code to respond to changes in the collection like this.

```cs
// Observe the collection somewhere where it is safe to do so
viewModel.images.CollectionChanged += HandChanged;
...
        private readonly List<ColumnDefinition> ColumnDefinitions = new();
        private readonly List<string> ImagePaths = new();
        private readonly List<Image> Images = new();

        private void HandChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (string item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    HandGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Remove(ColumnDefinitions[^1]);
                    ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1);
                    Images.RemoveAt(ImagePaths.IndexOf(item));
                    ImagePaths.Remove(item);
                }
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (string item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    ColumnDefinition cd = new()
                    {
                        Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                    };
                    ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
                    HandGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);

                    Image image = new() {
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(FileUtil.GetFullPath(item))),
                        Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
                    };
                    
                    Images.Add(image);
                    ImagePaths.Add(item);
                    Grid.SetColumn(image, Images.Count - 1);
                    HandGrid.Children.Add(image);
                }
            }
        }
```